# htaccess какие файлы нужно запретить при разработке сайта с нуля?

Tags: .htaccess

При использовании такой классики, как phpmyadmin, composer, smarty

на php папки и папки конфигов стоит deny all
В корне htaccess стоит доступ только по паролю
Но есть специфические статьи, словно говорящие, что нужно запрещать еще и сам htaccess и его htpassword

Я не могу протестировать некоторые вещи, что нужно запрещать, так как моя панель делает это отчасти за меня и немного меня путает, а ставить чистый php-апач-бд с нуля и конспектирование займет неделю, а данные нужны сейчас

русский гугл молчит

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

По классике вам следует разместить все ваши исходники в папке недоступной по http. То есть в папке за пределами public_html. В public_html у вас останутся только css, js, картинки и index.php, который будет реквайрить ваш index.php из папки с исходниками или симлинк.

Средства администрирования такие как phpmyadmin вообще не надо устанавливать рядом с вашим сайтом. Пользуйтесь локальным клиентом (тем же phpmyadmin установленном на вашем компе или клиентом в IDE) и заведите отдельного пользователя бд для администрирования.

Если сделаете так, то запрещать ничего не понадобится.